# how to split Strings into Arrays?

Tags: powershell

how can I have $data outside my .Click event to later use in a different .Click event:

```
Username       : John
Device         : Lenovo T15
Headset        : Hyper Cloud 2
Dockingstation : Wavelink
Monitor        : HP
Transponder    : 002
```

I want to obtain each line individually, for instance: `$array[1] = "John"`, `$array[2] = "Lenovo T15"` and so on. I was just able to get something like that: `John Device`.

Output getting gathered from a csv and displayed on Textbox in an GUI builded script:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$csvData = Import-Csv -path 'C:\temp\offboarding_skript.csv' -Header "Username", "Device", "Headset", "Dockingstation", "Monitor", "Transponder" 


function search_csv {
    $searchThis = $textbox_Search.Text.Trim()
    # use $script: scoping here to reference the $csvData variable
    $data = $script:csvData | Where-Object {$_.Username -like "*$searchThis*"}
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($searchThis)) {
        $output_TextBox.Clear()
    }
    elseif ($data) {
        $output_TextBox.Text =  ($data| Format-List | Out-String).Trim() 
    }

    else {
        $output_TextBox.Text = "Nichts gefunden .."

        }
      }

     
    $search_csvtool = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $search_csvtool.Text = "Offboarding-Skript"
    $search_csvtool.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(674,500)
    $search_csvtool.FormBorderStyle ="FixedDialog"
    $search_csvtool.Backcolor="white"
    $search_csvtool.TopMost = $true
    $search_csvtool.MaximizeBox = $false
    $search_csvtool.MinimizeBox = $true
    $search_csvtool.ControlBox = $true
    $search_csvtool.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $search_csvtool.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif"


    $label_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,18)
    $label_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(265,32)
    $label_Search.TextAlign ="MiddleCenter"
    $label_Search.Text = "Bitte Nutzernamen eingeben:"
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($label_Search)


    $textbox_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textbox_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,50)
    $textbox_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,37)
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($textbox_Search)


    $button_Search = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_Search.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(195,80)
    $button_Search.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(266,24)
    $button_Search.TextAlign = "MiddleCenter"
    $button_Search.Text = "Suche"
    $button_Search.Add_Click({search_csv})
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($button_Search) 


    $output_TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $output_TextBox.Multiline = $true;
    $output_TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,130)
    $output_TextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,250)
    $output_TextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $output_TextBox.ReadOnly = $true;
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($output_TextBox)
    $search_csvtool.Add_Shown({$search_csvtool.Activate()})

    
    #Print Button zum drucken der ausgegebenen Textzeile
    $PrintButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $PrintButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,420)
    $PrintButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $PrintButton.Text = "Drucken"
    $PrintButton.Name = "Drucken"
    $PrintButton.Add_Click(({#Path
$template = "c:\tempory\Inventarliste.docx"
$tempFolder = $env:TEMP + "\Populate-Word-DOCX"

# unzip function
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip {
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}
function Zip {
    param([string]$folderInclude, [string]$outZip)
    [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]$compression = "Optimal"
    $ziparchive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open( $outZip, "Update" )

    # loop all child files
    $realtiveTempFolder = (Resolve-Path $tempFolder -Relative).TrimStart(".\")
    foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $folderInclude -Recurse)) {
        # skip directories
        if ($file.GetType().ToString() -ne "System.IO.DirectoryInfo") {
            # relative path
            $relpath = ""
            if ($file.FullName) {
                $relpath = (Resolve-Path $file.FullName -Relative)
            }
            if (!$relpath) {
                $relpath = $file.Name
            } else {
                $relpath = $relpath.Replace($realtiveTempFolder, "")
                $relpath = $relpath.TrimStart(".\").TrimStart("\\")
            }

            # display
            Write-Host $relpath -Fore Green
            Write-Host $file.FullName -Fore Yellow

            # add file
            [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::CreateEntryFromFile($ziparchive, $file.FullName, $relpath, $compression) | Out-Null
        }
    }
    $ziparchive.Dispose()
}

# prepare folder
Remove-Item $tempFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
mkdir $tempFolder | Out-Null

# unzip DOCX
Unzip $template $tempFolder

# replace text
$bodyFile = $tempFolder + "\word\document.xml"
$body = Get-Content $bodyFile
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder1]", "$Username")
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder2]", "$Device")
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder3]", "$Headset")
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder4]", "$Dockingstation")
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder5]", "$Monitor")
$body = $body.Replace("[placeholder6]", "$Transponder")
$body | Out-File $bodyFile -Force -Encoding ascii

# zip DOCX
$destfile = $template.Replace(".docx", "-after.docx")
Remove-Item $destfile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Zip $tempFolder $destfile

# clean folder
Remove-Item $tempFolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Confirm:$false | Out-Null}))
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($PrintButton) 


    #Abbrechen Button
    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560,420)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Abbrechen"
    $CancelButton.Name = "Abbrechen"
    $CancelButton.DialogResult = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
    $search_csvtool.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
    

    
     
  

  

    [void] $search_csvtool.ShowDialog()
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: so how to read out my expected output, if it is an object?

Comment: i just updated my question. The script is builded to firstly have the information about the searched user, if he even exists. In the further script i have a export button, thats export each value into a template word documents. Thats why i need the values line per line.

Comment: How to call it properly?  i don't get any value by calling $data? only by looking at $output_textbox.text, but this gives me all the output.

Comment: instead of trying to parse `$output_TextBox.Text` your question should be: "how can I have `$data` outside my `.Click` event to later use in a different `.Click` event"

Comment: im still learning powershell, so my question selection isnt the best, sorry.

Comment: no need to be sorry. I'm trying to teach you how to approach the problem. please add the code you have for your "Export" click event

Comment: i just uploaded the whole script i have so far, thanks.

Comment: I assume the part where you need help is just below the comment `# replace text` right?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing mainly on the parts of the code where you are in need of help, first your "search" function which for the most part is correct, you just need a way to preserve the `$data` result outside of the scope of your `Click` event, for that we can use any reference type, in this case a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2).

```
# import Csv here as you're already doing
$csvData = Import-Csv 'C:\temp\offboarding_skript.csv' -Header ....

# we will use this hashtable to store the `$data`
# in the parent scope so we can re-use it in the `$PrintButton` Click Event
$result  = @{}

function search_csv {
    $searchThis = $textbox_Search.Text.Trim()

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($searchThis)) {
        # exit early
        return $output_TextBox.Clear()
    }

    # no need for `$script:` to read a parent scope variable,
    # not sure where you got that information but is wrong
    $data = $csvData | Where-Object { $_.Username -like "*$searchThis*" }

    if($data) {
        # here we can send `$data` to the parent scope
        $result['Value'] = $data
        $output_TextBox.Text = ($data | Format-List | Out-String).Trim()
        # exit early from this event
        return
    }

    # if above conditions were false, then we can assume
    # no object was found, remove the Value from the outside hashtable
    $result.Remove('Value')
    $output_TextBox.Text = "Nichts gefunden .."
}
```

Now that we have `$data` (an actual `PSCustomObject`) we don't have a need to parse or split or anything else but dot notation to get it's values. Note that, probably here you will need to handle what happens if there is more than 1 result from your search (should this create more than Xml?), its also worth noting you shouldn't be treating an Xml as plain text and doing plain text replacement but that's out of the scope of this question.

```
# rest of the code is left as-is, focusing in this event
$PrintButton.Add_Click({
    # start of this event can remain as-is...

    # this is the part where you needed help, here we can do this:
    $data = $result['Value']
    # now `$data` is the same object or objects that resulted from
    # the `search_csv` function!

    $bodyFile = $tempFolder + "\word\document.xml"
    $body = Get-Content $bodyFile -Raw

    # since `$data` is an object we can just use dot notation here!
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder1]", $data.UserName)
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder2]", $data.Device)
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder3]", $data.Headset)
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder4]", $data.Dockingstation)
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder5]", $data.Monitor)
    $body = $body.Replace("[placeholder6]", $data.Transponder)
    $body | Out-File $bodyFile -Force -Encoding ascii

    # rest of this event remain as-is....
})
$search_csvtool.Controls.Add($PrintButton)
```

Comment: many thanks to you man, it works as intended. Next time i will try to put better information to my questions. Do you mind when i delete the old post, cause of duplicate?

Comment: @Raindrop197 I'm glad it helped. please dont take it the hard way, my intent was to teach you a better way at solving the problem. yeah you should delete the old duplicate cause it's mostly the same question